# Get mapCoordinates (latitude, longitude) from Gmaps.Geolocate

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-maps, reactjs

I am developing a ReactJs webapp that renders a google maps API. But when my app starts should show a user location. Where lat and lng is set null should be get user geolocation (latitude and longitude). There is another function from Gmaps, I need to only set currentAddress, mapCoordinates (lat, lng) with user location.

```
    var App = React.createClass({



getInitialState(){


    GMaps.geolocate({
    success: function(position) {

        //alert("Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + 
        //"<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude); //it's works


        var userLat = position.coords.latitude;
        var userLng = position.coords.longitude;    

    },
    error: function(error) {
        alert('Geolocation failed: '+error.message);
    },
    not_supported: function() {
        alert("Your browser does not support geolocation");
    },
    always: function() {
        //alert("Done!");
    },

    });

    return {

        mapCoordinates: {

            //lat: userLat, //how to get userLat 
            //lng: userLng //how to get userLng

        }                           

    }


},

...
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @76484 I want to get `userLat` and `userLng` values from `sucess function` to `mapCoordinates` on return

Comment: I solved it using `this.setState` `self.setState({
            mapCoordinates: {
              lat: userLat,
              lng: userLng
            }
          });` in my async function `sucess`.